# Using singleton pattern to have multiple creators

Tags: php, singleton

I am using the singleton pattern for a site, and for this users need to be able to register. I want to be able to to use the same `Init()` function across many functions and wanted to know of the best way to do this.

So far what I have is this:

```
<?php
class User
{
    public static $username;
    public static $email;

    private static $init;
    private static $link;

    private function __construct() 
    {
        if (!static::$link)
        {
            global $link;
            if (isset($link))
                static::$link = $link;
            else
                die("Failed to get link.");
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public static function Init()
    {
        return static::$init = (
                null === static::$init ? new self() : static::$init
            );
    }

    public static function Register($username, $password, $email, $role)
    {
        return static::Init(); /* Only returning this for testing purposes */
    }
}
```

I have tested this and the `$user = User::Init()` call works, but for some reason the static function `Register` does not go into the private `__construct` when running and is therefore not checking the links status.

What is the issue with this?

I do not get any errors and have error reporting on

Comment: Just because it can be designed this way it doesn't mean it should be. Why would you consider realizing this with a singleton pattern?

Comment: I always want the single instance of the User class and (IMO), the best way for this is the Singleton design pattern

Comment: I think technically you want a single row from the database and perform a bunch of actions on that row (create a new one for signing up, update, send mail, deactivate etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have tried out your code, but it seems to work fine. I've added some var dumps and see the output:

```
<?php
class User
{
    public static $username;
    public static $email;

    private static $init;
    private static $link;

    private function __construct() 
    {
        var_dump(__CLASS__ . ' in method ' . __FUNCTION__ );
        if (!static::$link)
        {
            global $link;
            if (isset($link))
                static::$link = $link;
            else
                die("Failed to get link.");
            return;
        }
        return;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public static function Init()
    {
        var_dump(__CLASS__ . ' in method ' . __FUNCTION__ );
        return static::$init = (
                null === static::$init ? new self() : static::$init
            );
    }

    public static function Register($username, $password, $email, $role)
    {
        var_dump(__CLASS__ . ' in method ' . __FUNCTION__ );
        return static::Init(); /* Only returning this for testing purposes */
    }
}

$link = true; // dummy var to satisfy your __construct method
$user = User::Register(1,2,3,4);
```

Output:

```
string 'User in method Register' (length=23)
string 'User in method Init' (length=19)
string 'User in method __construct' (length=26)
```

Seems like expected or am I missing something?